# ko.validation.group not recognized

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

This is the line i am facing problem with :

```
viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel);
```

It is showing error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined

any of the `ko.validation.*` is not recognized

I am Using `jquery-1.7.1.js`,`knockout2.1.0`,`knockout-validator.js` and want validations over some fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really using the correct file? Its name is

> knockout.validation.js

https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation